# Programatically mount SkyDrive Share given username and password

Tags: onedrive

Is there a way to programaticallymount SkyDrive Share given the users credential?

Answer (score 0):

you can use webdav to mount an net disk to local.
the skydrive webdav url can obtain by this [SkyDrive Simple View for WebDav](http://skydrivesimpleviewer.codeplex.com/releases/view/39725)